# Project Euler #3 Java: Why count up to square root when finding the largest prime factor, rather than counting down from square root?

Tags: java, for-loop, prime-factoring

I'm trying to solve problem 3 of project Euler and I have written the following code which gives me the correct answer
public class LargestPrimeFactor {

```
public static boolean isPrime(int p) {
    boolean isPrime = true;
    for (int i = 2; i < p / 2; i++) {
        if (p % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return isPrime;
}

public static double largestPrimeFactor(long n) {
    double factor = 0;

    for (int j=1; j<Math.sqrt(n); j++) {
        System.out.println("j is : "+ j);
        if (n % j == 0 && isPrime(j)) {
        factor = j;
        }
    }
    return factor;
}


public static void main(String args[]) {
    long limit = 600851475143L;
    System.out.println(largestPrimeFactor(limit));

}}
```

I was wondering wether it is a good idea to start at 1 and increase towards the square root, when we are looking for the largest factor. So I tried to change the for loop in the largestPrimeFactor(long n) method to start from the square root of n and count down. However now I get an incorrect answer. What is the reason for this?

```
public class LargestPrimeFactor {

public static boolean isPrime(int p) {
    boolean isPrime = true;
    for (int i = 2; i < p / 2; i++) {
        if (p % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return isPrime;
}

public static double largestPrimeFactor(long n) {
    double factor = 0;

    for (int j=(int)Math.sqrt(n); 1<j; j--) {
        System.out.println("j is : "+ j);


        if (n % j == 0 && isPrime(j)) {
            factor = j;
        }

    }
    return factor;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    long limit = 600851475143L;
    System.out.println(largestPrimeFactor(limit));

}}
```

Comment: do you break after finding the first prime factor (since the first one is largest and you don't have to search any further)?

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem! But does it make more sense to count up or count down?

Comment: Why are you counting to the square root? Largest prime factor can be larger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a break after finding the first prime factor - the first you find is the largest and you shouldn't search any further. For that you should return the first correct value you find like this

```
public static double largestPrimeFactor(long n) {
    double factor = 0;

    for (int j=(int)Math.sqrt(n); 1<j; j--) {
        if (n % j == 0 && isPrime(j)) {
            return j; // Changed this line
        }

    }
    return factor;
}
```